# Checking Segue after it initiated

Tags: swift, segue

I have two `UIViewController`: A, B

Lets say there are two segues connecting them: C, D

Once a `segue` has been activated and I am in view B, can I know which segue got me here? C or D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prepare(for: segue) function that allows you to set a property in the new ViewController.

```
class OriginViewController : UIViewController {

    ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SegueProtocol {
            destination.transitionSegue = segue.identifier
        }
    }
}

class DestinationViewController : UIViewController, SegueProtocol {
    var transitionSegue: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("Segue: ", transitionSegue)
    }
}

protocol SegueProtocol {
    var transitionSegue : String { get set }
}
```

Edit: As per comment suggestion, it's better to expect a destination that conforms to a protocol rather than one of a specific type.

Comment: not prepare. That is checking BEFORE I get to B. I want it after

Comment: It can accomplish both. Once you are in B, you will have a `howIGotHere` property that was set in the `prepare()` method.

Comment: It would be better to make the destination conform to a protocol that defines the `howIGotHere` var rather than having the source view controller expect a specific subclass of UIViewController (looser coupling makes for more flexible code.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built-in mechanism for this, but you could have all your destination view controllers conform to a protocol `SourceSegueProtocol` that has a var to contain the invoking segue.

Then in the source view controller's `prepare(for:sender:)` method you could set that variable for destination view controllers that conform to the `SourceSegueProtocol`.